# What does the 3rd tuple value stand for in Pillow.Image.tile?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Could someone tell me what 106 stands for in the following output generated by printing the Pillow.Image.tile attribute?

```
[('zip', (0, 0, 242, 80), 106, 'RGBA')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [*Using PIL on Large Images*](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-large-images.htm):

> The third item is the offset from the start of the file to the data for that tile.

the data for that tile is 106 bytes into the raw stream.

The tile itself is 80 * 242 * 4 (RGBA) == 77440 bytes, so a *next* tile would be found at offset 106 + 77440. Provided the tile didn't cover the whole image to begin with, of course.

Your `tile` information shows the image data is compressed (the first argument is `'zip'`) so you cannot here set `tile` to a smaller area and handle the file in sub-sections. That only works for `'raw'` image data.

Further documentation can be found in the [*Writing Your Own File Decoder*](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/writing-your-own-file-decoder.html?highlight=tile#the-tile-attribute) section of the Pillow documentation:

> **offset**
>   Byte offset from the beginning of the file to image data.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand it correctly, there's a 106 byte long header, followed by the actual image data?

Comment: @bsuire: looks like it.